# How to define mTLS authentication in OpenAPI 3.0.x?

Tags: openapi

As the authentication type mTLS is not supported in OAS 3.0.X version and support is provided in OAS 3.1.

We are on OAS 3.0.X version and looking for a way to define that the API uses mTLS authentication. I can think of using OpenAPI extension in security schemes, but still it expects only the allowed authentication types like - http, apiKey, oauth, etc.

Any thoughts are ideas if anyone has already done this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

OAS 3.0.x clearly mentioned Security Scheme Object where type field defines only below values:
`apiKey`, `http`, `oauth2`, `openIdConnect`

In this case, if you specify anything thing as value, it will fail the validation and there is [no other way to specify mTLS (Mutual TLS)](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.0#security-scheme-object) with this version. If you keep type as `http` then scheme need to defined which supports [Authentication Schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) but it also does not have mTLS support.

If you are ready to migrate with OAS 3.1.x then there is specific value `mutualTLS` defined for [mTLS](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#security-scheme-object).

So only option to migrate to OAS 3.1.x version to provide a valid way for mTLS.